# Appium Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios-provisioning, appium

Team,

Can anyone clarify about "Development distribution profile" mentioned in Appium Site? Is it Developer Profile or Distribution Profile or it works on both profile?

PROVISIONING PROFILE

A valid iOS Development Distribution Certificate and Provisioning Profile are necessary to test on a real device. Your app will also need to be signed. You can find information about this in the Apple documentation.

http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#appium-on-real-ios-devices

Please refer the below link,
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/9GA4XdsnM4A
Comment by Anil Kumar on 29/11/2013

1. Build has to be signed with developer certificate/ profile (not distribution profile),

Thanks,
Ramesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html) you need to have your application signed with a development provisioning profile in order to be able to exercise your app via UIAutomation.

Since Appium uses UIAutomation, I understand that you need to have your app signed with a development provisioning profile to be able to write automated tests for it in Appium.

Comment: For browser automation also Provisional profile is needed? Planning to use safari for automation